# How to serve from different locations in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I want to have different sub-websites inside my website, in such a way that each of them matches to a different location.

For example, `<website>/game/` should serve stuff from `/var/www/<gamePath>`, and `<website>/<blog>` should serve stuff from `/var/www/<blogPath>`. As a default, `<website>/<anything>` should serve stuff form `/var/www/html/`.

My current config looks like this:

```
server {
 server_name <website>;
 root /var/www/html;

 location / {
   try_files $uri /index.html =404;
 }

 location /game/ {
   root /var/www/<gamePath>/;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
 
 location /blog/ {
   root /var/www/<blogPath>/;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
  <ssl stuff>
}
```

While the default location works, and `<website>` correctly serves the file `/var/www/html/index.html`, when I try to do `<website>/blog/favicon.ico`, it does not serve the favicon, but instead defaults to `/var/www/<blogPath>/index.html`. It seems that this is because it is appending `blog` (the location) to the uri, and does it won't match anything.

I have seen many questions around this issue, but no answer has worked for me so far. Some replace the `root` inside each specific location by `alias`, but if I do that I only get 404's. Other solutions try rewriting the request instead of using $uri, in order to avoid the location being appended. This seems like the way to go, but I haven't found a regex that actually works (maybe they require trivial modifications that I haven't been able to do myself, as all I've tried is to copy and paste them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nginx `root` directive works by adding the URI part from the `location` to the end of file path it tries to serve to the user.

So, in your example, loading `/game/example` URL makes nginx look up the file `/var/www/<gamePath>/game/example`.

To make `/game/example` load `/var/www/<gamePath>/example`, you need to use following configuration.

```
location ~ ^/game/(?<filepath>.*)$ {
    root /var/www/<gamePath>/;
    try_files /$filepath /$filepath/ /index.html =404;
}
```

This tells nginx to capture the string after `/game` to `$filepath` variable, which is then used to locate the file.

Another alternative is to use `alias` instead of `root`.

Comment: The only comment I have is that now, if I try to access `<website>/game/` it does not give me the `index.html` of the game location but instead the one of the `/` location.

Comment: I updated the answer by changing locations of the `/` characters. Hope it helps.

Comment: I suspect just using `alias` would be a lot cleaner.

Comment: That is true. I had the impression of `root` being faster option here, but with the regex capturing this approach might be slower.

Comment: @Michael Hampton I tried replacing "root" with "alias" inside the locations but I kept getting 404.